# Running concurrent firebase requests using promises

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, promise, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to execute number of Firebase Cloud Storage queries concurrently using Promise.all() :

```
exports.onNewOrder = 
functions.database.ref('/orders/{orderId}').onCreate(event => {  
    const data = event.val();
    const orderedBy = data.ordered_by;
    const creations = data.creations;

    var promises = []
    for (var entry of creations.entries()) {
        var key = entry[0], value = entry[1];
        var creationPromise = admin.database().ref("creations/"+ key);
        creationPromise.once("value")
        .then((crSnapshot)=>{
            const crName = crSnapshot.val().name;
            const created = crSnapshot.val().created;
            return "crName+'\n'+created”;
        }).catch((error) => {
            console.log("creation details error : "+ error);
        });
        promises.push(creationPromise);
    }

    const userPromise = admin.database().ref("users/"+ orderedBy);
    userPromise.once("value")
    .then((snapshot) => {
        var name = snapshot.val().name;
        var email = snapshot.val().email;
        const userDetails = name+'\n'+email;
        return userDetails; 
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log("user details error :"+ error);
    });

    promises.push(userPromise);

    return Promise.all(promises).then(results => {
        console.log("results: " + results)
        return true;
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log("sendMail failed : "+ error);
    });
});
```

I am expecting to see complete query result for every executed promise, however I am getting the following instead:

results:

```
https://....firebaseio.com/creations/cr_1bfd5f16212f44c792a2cbe3e9c6e4cc
https://....firebaseio.com/creations/cr_343c363c2a214487ba8cb7101653f6af
https://....firebaseio.com/creations/cr_e3f7a0bafd1542ac898d96e86155b94e
https://....firebaseio.com/users/us_5e4c28e18e63454c861caa5c4fe6a6f0
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: By the way, you've got none of your questions labeled as answered. Accepting answers and upvoting them is one of few ways we have to encourage other users to help us on SO; also makes easier for other users to find helpful posts. If you don't show any interest in answers, why would anyone spare time to write them?

Comment: Good point. How do I label question as answered ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should do the trick.

As detailed [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all):

> The `Promise.all(iterable)` method returns a single Promise that
>   resolves when all of the promises in the `iterable` argument have
>   resolved or when the `iterable` argument contains no promises. It
>   rejects with the reason of the first promise that rejects.

Therefore you need to add some promises to the `promises` array.

The `once()` method does return a promise, as explained [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.database.Reference#once) in the doc.

```
exports.onNewOrder = 
functions.database.ref('/orders/{orderId}').onCreate(event => {  
    const data = event.val();
    const orderedBy = data.ordered_by;
    const creations = data.creations;

    const promises = []

    for (var entry of creations.entries()) {
        var key = entry[0];
        var creationPromise = admin.database().ref("creations/"+ key).once("value");
        promises.push(creationPromise);
    }

    const userPromise = admin.database().ref("users/"+ orderedBy).once("value");
    promises.push(userPromise);

    return Promise.all(promises)
    .then(results => {
        console.log("results: " + results);
        return true;
        //actually here you will probably do something else than just write the results to the console. 
        //In this case you should return a promise (instead of true).
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log("sendMail failed : "+ error);
        return false;
    });

});
```

Comment: Thanks, promises seem to be working now, though console shows `results: [object Object]`. am I still missing something?

Comment: Result from `Promise.all(promises)` is normally an array with all the results of the promises, in the same order you pushed the promises in the `promises` array. So something must be wrong but it is difficult to know exactly why without more details.

Comment: I forgot to thank you for your last comment. Thanks a lot!  It helped: return Promise.all(promises)
    .then(results => {
        results.forEach(element => {
           …
        });
        return sendMail(orderid, text);
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log("sendMail failed : "+ error);
    });

Comment: Glad I could help you! You may accept my answer, by clicking the grey checkmark to the left of the answer. Thanks